# Turn off WiFi only when the device is both locked and screen turned off

Tags: wi-fi, screen, automation

I have already tested some apps for this purpose and they solely rely on the screen turning off, which makes sense at some point. However, their concept breaks down when you want to use an app over WiFi which has the capability to turn-off the screen due to the proximity sensor (think of the VoIP apps). Turning off the screen in that case means disconnection from the network.

Is it possible to turn off the WiFi only if the device is both locked and screen turned off?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then there is a *very* easy way of doing this yourself. Im sure there are *many* ways of going about this, but this is the easiest and most reliable method that I know of.

You said that you wanted something that doesn't rely on the screen being off. My solution does rely on the "display" being off, however for the "display" as opposed to the "screen" to be off, the device *must* be locked, meaning that this should work flawlessly for you.

If you just follow the instructions I've provided below, you should have satisfying results in just a few minutes!

---

1. Download **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** from the **Play Store.**
2. Open **Tasker** and click the `+` button. Now click **Event** → **Display** → **Display Off.**
3. Click the **gear** (back button) in the **top left corner.** A pop up menu will appear. Select **New Task** and name it `Display Off`.
4. Tap `+` → **Net** → **WiFi** and make sure the box that says **Set** is set to `Off`.
5. Click the gear (back) twice so that you end up on the **Profiles** screen.
6. Now click `+` again, then **Event** → **Display** → **Display On.**
7. Tap the gear (back) and then select **New Task**. Name it something along the lines of `Display On`.
8. Click `+` → **Net** → **WiFi** and change **Set** to `On`. Now exit back to the **Profiles** tab. You should now have both **Display Off** and **Display On.**
9. In the **Profiles** tab to the right of your conditions, there are **On/ Off** toggles. Turn both of these to <kbd>Off</kbd> and then back to <kbd>On</kbd>.
10. Simply exit out of **Tasker** and you're done!

---

Good luck and I hope this helps you!

Comment: how will this behave in case that I use an app which turns the display off due to proximity sensor? Will it turn off the wifi radio then as well?

Comment: @KristofPal it *should* turn off the wifi radio with the app your talking about.

Comment: Do you need root for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly... 
There is a setting under `WiFi` -> `More` -> `Keep WiFi on during sleep`

[image: wifi settings]

<sup>click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: forgot to mention I tried that... still able to ping the phone when locked... wierd

Comment: This is probably because with all apps running, the phone never enters sleep mode, so the setting is pretty much useless.